# Changing position of my image in mozilla and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image which is always changing position when viewed in chrome and mozilla. When I make it look perfect in chrome it changes position in mozilla while when i make it look perfect for mozilla it changes position for chrome. How can I make image not to change position in different browser.

```
#economy123{
 position:absolute;
top:67%;
left:53%;
  }



<div class="result-temp"  >
 <img id="economy123" src="{{ asset('assets/images/economy123.png') }}" >
    <p class="t"></p>
```

Comment: We can't understand much from that chunk of code. Also tell us how exactly it changes position. What the difference between FF and Chrome?

Comment: When I resize the window the image overlaps with text.....and it is on a different place in chrome and different in mozilla originally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code isn't so clear but you can set a specific position for FF only using `@-moz-document url-prefix()`:

```
#economy123{
    position:absolute;
    top:67%;
    left:53%;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    #economy123{
        top:55%; //different
        left:43%; //different
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a solution for making it stable but when I resize the window I mean change my browser window size then image position changes ...Thanks

Comment: Did your problem is `When I make it look perfect in chrome it changes position in mozilla while when i make it look perfect for mozilla it changes position for chrome.`? if yes, make it look perfect in chrome in first class (#economy123) and make it look perfect in Mozilla in second class under `@-moz-document url-prefix()` the Chrome read position from first and Mozilla read position from second and ignore first.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

try putting this in the head of your html document, it should make your pictures look the same on all devices and browsers.